# XAMPP mysql command dosen't work from cmd prompt after port change

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have changed XAMPP mysql port at three places,
[client] 
port            = 3307
[mysqld]
port= 3307 
 `in my.ini`
and one in `config.inc.php` (`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3307';`)
With all this changes, everything runs fine, except mysql command through CMD.
This is the error.

[image]

Everything, even the cmd works fine when port is `3306`, but when port is changed to any other port, everything works fine except cmd.
Please help me out in solving this and in learning something different.

Comment: Did you restart XAMPP?

Comment: many times. But still didn't work